# Javascript creating new textbox on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript function in which i am trying to create a new textbox on button click. But the new row is being created below the current row and the data is from top row is being transferred to the row below.
 I am trying a way through which the first row is not set to null and the data from the first row  reamins as it is and a second new row is created blank.
Can anyone help me pls.

**My Code**

```
 function GetDynamicTextBox() {
            var value1 = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
            var value2 = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
            var value3 = document.getElementById("txtPhone").value;
            return '<div> <input name="txtdynamicname" class="textboxSmall" id="txtdynamicname" type="text" value= "' + value1 + '" />&nbsp;' +
                '<input name = "txtdynamicemail" class="textboxSmall" id="txtdynamicemail" type="text" value = "' + value2 + '" />&nbsp;' +
                    '<input name = "txtdynamicphone" class="textboxSmall" id="txtdynamicphone" type="text" value = "' + value3 + '" />&nbsp;' +
                        '<input type="Image" id="txtdynamicbutton" src="Images/Minus.jpg" CausesValidation="false" onclick = "javascript:return RemoveTextBox(this)" /> </div>';
        }

        //Add Textboxes in the div - New Data + Existing Data
        function AddTextBox() {
            if (document.getElementById("txtName").value != "") {
                if (PassengerLimit > 1) {
                    PassengerLimit = PassengerLimit - 1;
                    //Get Text

                    var ExistingData = document.createElement('DIV');
                    ExistingData.innerHTML = Container.innerHTML;

                    var NewData = document.createElement('DIV');
                    // NewData.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox() + Container.innerHTML;
                    NewData.innerHTML = Container.innerHTML + GetDynamicTextBox();



                    //Clear All Data
                    Container.innerHTML = "";

                    //append New Data
                    Container.innerHTML = NewData.innerHTML;

                    //append existing Data
                    // Container.appendChild(ExistingData);


                    document.getElementById("txtName").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("txtEmail").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("txtPhone").value = "";
                }
                else {
                    alert("Sorry! You can add only 10 Passengers detail");
                }


            }
            else
            {
                alert("Sorry! Please fill passengers details.");
             //   return true;
            } return false;
        }
```

**First Image**
[image: This image before clicking add button]

---

---

**Second Image**

[image: After Clicking Add Button]

Comment: Could you put this in JSFiddle and share?

Comment: use _document.getElementById('existing_div').innerHTML += new_div;_

Comment: @JohnTheBeloved : can u pls elaborate

Answer (score 0):

In GetDynamicTextBox() you could try getting a simple html structure what you wanted with no values init and use it.

function GetDynamicTextBox() {

```
        return '<div> <input name="txtdynamicname" class="textboxSmall" id="txtdynamicname" type="text" value="" />&nbsp;' +
            '<input name = "txtdynamicemail" class="textboxSmall" id="txtdynamicemail" type="text" value ="" />&nbsp;' +
                '<input name = "txtdynamicphone" class="textboxSmall" id="txtdynamicphone" type="text" value ="" />&nbsp;' +
                    '<input type="Image" id="txtdynamicbutton" src="Images/Plus.jpg" CausesValidation="false" onclick = "javascript:return AddTextBox()" /> </div>';
    }

    //Add Textboxes in the div - New Data + Existing Data
    function AddTextBox() {
        if (document.getElementById("txtName").value != "") {
            if (PassengerLimit > 1) {
                PassengerLimit = PassengerLimit - 1;
                //Get Text

                var ExistingData = document.createElement('DIV');
                ExistingData.innerHTML = Container.innerHTML;

                var NewData = document.createElement('DIV');
                // NewData.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox() + Container.innerHTML;
                NewData.innerHTML = Container.innerHTML + GetDynamicTextBox();



                //Clear All Data
                Container.innerHTML = "";

                //append New Data
                Container.innerHTML = NewData.innerHTML;

                //append existing Data
                // Container.appendChild(ExistingData);


            }
            else {
                alert("Sorry! You can add only 10 Passengers detail");
            }


        }
        else
        {
            alert("Sorry! Please fill passengers details.");
         //   return true;
        } return false;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this. this way i loose data. bcoz when i click submit.. the string where i append data is lost..

Comment: you could try appending it rather forming full html with the prev texbox elements...for that you can hav a parent div on top of all these current div's that you are trying to create dynamically and give a id to the parent div get it's html and append the dynamically created new div every time you want to add one.